# In the C# String constructor, String(Char*), why doesn't the constructor expect a pointer to an array of characters?

Tags: c#, .net, string, pointers, char

I've used C# for several years but have never worked with Pointers in C#. I'm playing around with the String API and I'm lost on why a char* is actually an array and not a single char.

The API defintion:

```
[System.CLSCompliant(false)]
public String (char* value);
```

A snippet of the API documentation:

### Parameters

**value** `Char*`

A pointer to a null-terminated array of Unicode characters.

---

Is the declaration `char* singleChar` a pointer to a single char? The pointer docs [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types) seems to say so.

So, why/how can it also be a pointer to an array? Why isn't the parameter type `char[]*`?

Comment: A pointer to an array is always a pointer to it's first element

Comment: And in this case the "array" (in truth a region of contiguous memory) is terminated by the null-terminator (the char with code 0)

Comment: The more correct description would be "a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of Unicode characters", but the term array is often used, even if incorrecttly... `fixed (char* pch = "Hello world") { string str2 = new String(pch + 5); }` few would say that `pch + 5` is an array for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char[]*` in C# is technically not possible because managed types (in this case char[]) cannot be pointers, the more correct would be `char**`. This is a little confusing having a pointer to a pointer, but think of it as nothing more than an array of char arrays.

A pointer in unsafe C# code is simply a reference to a region of memory. In the `C` language, char arrays are generally null-terminated (byte value of 0) using continuous blocks of memory for the strings. The same applies in C#, the `char*` is simply a pointer to a continuous block of memory of `char` type.

Example:

```
Memory address 0x10000000 : h
Memory address 0x10000002 : e
Memory address 0x10000004 : l
Memory address 0x10000006 : l
Memory address 0x10000008 : o
Memory address 0x1000000A : \0
```

In C#, you could have `char* ptr = (char*)0x10000000` - and the memory would point to the chars `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `\0`.

You can convert a single C# array to a `char*` using the `fixed` keyword, which pins the char array down, preventing garbage collection or memory movement.

```cs
char[] chars = new char[64];
// fill chars with whatever
fixed (char* charPtr = chars)
{
}
```

`chars` in the above example could also be a `string`.

Hope some of this info is useful.